# catch the index of a v-for looping and pass the index to a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select that is generated by a v-for, so it has an index, and I want to get the index of this select as the user selects, so I can use it in a function, how could I do this?

I've looked at several tutorials but I could not solve it, if I could put the index as a global variable, it would also solve it, because then I would get the variable and use it inside the function

```
<label for="userSelect">Selecione o usuario</label><br>
<select name="userSelect" id="userSelect" class="custom-select">
<option :value="user._id" @change="takeProperty" v-for="(user,index) in getUser" :key="index" >{{  user.nome  }}</option>
</select><br>
<label for="userSelect">Selecione a propriedade que ele terá acesso</label><br>
<input type="radio" v-for="(property,j) in listProperty" :key="j">Teste<br>
```

```
takeProperty: function(index){
   console.log(index) <= returns undefined
}
```

I hope to be able to retrieve the index of the select as the user selects different options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the `selectedIndex` property directly

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [{_id: 1, name: "user 1"}, {_id: 2, name: "user 2"}]
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log("index is " + event.target.selectedIndex)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select @change="onChange">
    <option v-for="user in users" :value="user._id">{{user.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude, thanks for the help, it really saved me.
but I'd like to ask you something else, where I can learn about these properties you mentioned above

Comment: Consensus best resource is [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/), e.g. [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can handle this. First, you'll need to move your `@change` event handler up to the `<select/>` element. Then you can use the special `$event` variable to get the index of the selected option (the `selectedIndex`). While this isn't the index variable from your v-for loop, the value should be the same.

Here's the updated code:

```
<select name="userSelect" id="userSelect" class="custom-select" @change="takeProperty($event.target.selectedIndex)">
  <option :value="user._id" v-for="(user,index) in getUser" :key="index" >{{  user.nome  }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am recieving index" is not defined :(

Comment: Sorry about that - I think I answered without looking at your code closely enough. I've updated my answer.